# Delete all folders in appdata/local except /microsoft/teams

Tags: powershell

\

i have this script that deletes c:\users\xxx\appdata\local
i want to delete all folders under local except appdata\local\micrsoft\teams

```
# Get a list of all local profiles on the target machine # 
$users = Get-ChildItem c:\users
foreach ($user in $users){
$folder = "C:\users\" + $user +"\AppData\Local"
Remove-Item $folder -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
```

Comment: you'd have to reference the folder name, but it's probably cleaner if you reference the *fullname* property and concatenate that to your string (*or use `join-path`*): `$folder = Join-Path $_.FullName "AppData\Local"`. Take a look at `-Exclude` part of `Remove-Item`, or `Get-ChildItem -Exclude`, and `Where-Oject`.

Answer (score 2):

it was easy actually just needed some research

```
# Get a list of all local profiles on the target machine # 
$users = Get-ChildItem c:\users
foreach ($user in $users){
$folder = "C:\users\" + $user +"\AppData\Local"
Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -Exclude microsoft | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
}
```